# Extract html table and create column in R

Tags: html, r, xml

I'm trying to extract the table on the following URL https://www.cenace.gob.mx/DocsMEM/OpeMdo/OfertaCompVent/OferVenta/MDA/Termicas/OfeVtaTermicaHor%20BCS%20MDA%20Hor%202018-12-26%20v2019%2002%2024_01%2000%2001.html

So far I've been trying to use

```
url <- getURL("https://www.cenace.gob.mx/DocsMEM/OpeMdo/OfertaCompVent/OferVenta/MDA/Termicas/OfeVtaTermicaHor%20BCS%20MDA%20Hor%202018-12-26%20v2019%2002%2024_01%2000%2001.html",.opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE) )
parse <- xmlParse(url, isHTML = TRUE)
r <- readHTMLTable(parse)
```

But only null tables are returned. I've some knowledge in XML, and as far as I understand, I can scrape html webpages just as XML files. But I can't find any specific node in order to do that.

Also, I would like to know how can I create a column with the Fecha value.

Thanks!